# Will I get any failure notification if I create a user with an invalid address?

Tags: user, user-management

When I, as an admin, create a new user, if I mistakenly provide an invalid email address in the email field for that user, will I get any failure notification or email from Salesforce? Is there any way for me to know that the email address I provided was invalid?

Answer (score 3):

I've just tested this. If you're talking about validation, yes:
[image]

However, if you're talking about an incorrect e-mail address. I've not had any notification from Salesforce when submitting one. Presumably you'd need to liaise with the user if they haven't had their password creation e-mail and double-check the e-mail they gave you is correct.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

No you won't get a notification if it was an incorrect email *(not invalid, formatting-wise)*. However, you can always go to users and filter the list by last login to see which users haven't logged into your org yet.